# div pagination overflow new line

Tags: css

I have a pagination div hat shows the pages: previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... next

```
<div id='page_navigation'></div>
```

But when i have more than 26 pages the pagination div overflows the container
Now i applied `{overflow:hidden;}` ad `{overflow:scroll;}` And these work just fine. But the overflow gets with hidden covered and with scroll i have this ugly scrollbar. Now what i want to is that the div has a certan width and then when the page div end is reached, the other pagenumbers are displayed in the container on a new line

so the pagination looks like this:

previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 ... next

CSS CODE

```
<style>
#page_navigation a{
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin:2px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none
}
.active_page{
    background:darkblue;
    color:white !important;

}
</style>
```

Comment: So limit the pagination boxes

Comment: and how do i do that, i a terrible with css

Comment: Do it programmatically, as you have really unfriendly UI